# Python: Remove special character in string

Tags: python, regex, pandas, replace

I've the following string in python, example:

```
"Peter North  /  John West"
```

Note that there are two spaces before and after the forward slash.

What should I do such that I can clean it to become

```
"Peter North_John West"
```

I tried using regex but I am not exactly sure how.
Should I use re.sub or pandas.replace?

Comment: What about `"Peter North / John West".replace(" / ", "_")` ?

Comment: Is it always two spaces, then a forward slash, then 2 spaces?  Or is the concern the forward slash?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
a = "Peter North  /  John West"
import re
a = re.sub(' +/ +','_',a)
```

Any number of spaces with slash followed by any number of slashes can be replaced by this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

In case of varying number of white spaces before and after `/`:

```
import re

re.sub("\s+/\s+", "_", "Peter North  /  John West")
# Peter North_John West
```